# How to increase daily Email capacity in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I am working on project using google appengine. Using appengine now i can send Email daily upto 100 only for one Application Id. But i  want to increase my Email capacity. how shall i increase my Email capacity. And if increase email capacity for one Application Id does it impact on Another Application Id also? And I want purchase Email Packs for Monthy basis is it possible then how can i purchase?
Any help? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is no question of programming; check https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail

Comment: Thanks P.J Meisch  i done it

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to enable billing in order to go beyond the original 100 email limit. With billing on you get 20k emails for free, If your app needs to send more than 20,000 messages per day, you can sign up for a [support package](https://cloud.google.com/support/) which entitles you to ask for a higher quota.

Comment: Thanks Jirungaray I got it.